# Issue trying to calculate how to calculate working hours, excluding bank holidays

Tags: time, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to calculate the difference between 2 dates to evaluate if my company has met a service level agreement.

The time is only measured between 8am and 6pm, Monday to Friday - and any (UK) bank holidays are excluded.

The Bank holidays are in a table called "Holidays" with "Date" as the column name:

[image: Bank Holidays]

The DAX calculated column formula I have so far is:

```
Time Lapsed (Sentinel to SNOW) = 
VAR Upper = TIME(8, 0, 0)   // Upper time boundary (8:00 AM)
VAR Lower = TIME(18, 0, 0)  // Lower time boundary (6:00 PM)
VAR StartDateTime = 'Sentinel SNOW'[Created in Sentinel]  // Column containing start date and time
VAR EndDateTime = 'Sentinel SNOW'[Opened]      // Column containing end date and time

VAR DaysInRange = 
    CALCULATE(
        NETWORKDAYS(StartDateTime, EndDateTime),
        FILTER(
            ALL(Holidays),
            Holidays[Date] >= StartDateTime &&
            Holidays[Date] <= EndDateTime
        )
    ) - 1

VAR StartTimeFraction = MOD(StartDateTime, 1)
VAR EndTimeFraction = MOD(EndDateTime, 1)

VAR FirstDayHours = 
    IF(
        NETWORKDAYS(StartDateTime, StartDateTime),
        IF(StartTimeFraction <= Lower, StartTimeFraction, IF(StartTimeFraction >= Upper, Upper, Lower)),
        Upper
    )
    
VAR LastDayHours = 
    IF(
        NETWORKDAYS(EndDateTime, EndDateTime),
        IF(EndTimeFraction >= Upper, EndTimeFraction - Upper, IF(EndTimeFraction <= Lower, Lower - EndTimeFraction, 0)),
        0
    )

RETURN (DaysInRange * (Upper - Lower)) + FirstDayHours + LastDayHours
```

The results, for example are:

StartDateTime: 26/07/2023 18:37:00
EndDateTime:   27/07/2023 08:04:01

The result is: -0.08

...which doesn't make sense.

It should be 4m 1s, which in decimal terms is 0.002789.

Can anyone see where the problem is in my DAX code?

Thanks, Mark